# iPad 2 stopped syncing with my MacBook, how do I fix it?

Tags: ipad, itunes, data-synchronization

My iPad 2 has simply stopped syncing to iTunes. I can still sync my iPhone, but syncing iPad 2 has no effect at all. It creates a backup and then simply says that the sync is finished without doing any thing at all.

I can still transfer files to different applications . For example, I can transfer some movies to CineXPlayer but cannot remove any app from the iPad 2 or even install any app on it through iTunes.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First reboot the iPad and then try syncing. If still unable to sync, make a backup (make sure your backup is current) and restore the device to it's factory setting and then restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Having suffered the same difficulty with my iPad2, I tried rebooting the iPad2 using the usual way with the slide to power off feature but at the same time I pushed the button at the bottom of the iPad2 that takes me back to my home screen or that if pushed twice will show the running apps.

The iPad2 rebooted (I had to push in the off/on button again during what appeared to be rebooting because the white Apple seemed to stay on).
After that, I was able immediately to synch like before, although trying to access Pages documents is still not working (that is, what I see on the iPad2 in Pages is different from what I see on iTunes for Pages documents and I can't move them back and forth using DiskAid the way I used to, but document features including moving back and forth seem to work in other apps).

It may be that the two button reboot is what was needed.  I haven't yet tried the iTunes music synching, though.

Answer (score 0):

When your iPad is attached click on its name in the left column of iTunes, then click on the "Apps" tab near the top on the right. Make sure the "Sync Apps" checkbox at the top is checked. The same applies to anything else that doesn't seem to be syncing.

Answer (score 0):

When iTunes transfers them it performs some sort of optimisation (which I'm not sure is documented anywhere), over which you have no control over. There are various photo transfer apps in the store that use wifi which may retain the quality - as I haven't tried any of them I don't know how good they are. 
Know more about [how to transfer or sync iPad contents to Mac](http://www.softwarebbs.com/wiki/How_to_transfer_or_sync_iPad_contents_to_Mac), which included the detailed tutorials of how to sync your iPad2 to Mac. 
Hopefully this works for all of you like it just worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring the iPad and then try syncing. Or delete the backups in the settings section, then try syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the options you have set in your "apps" menu and such?

Try a different cord, or, if all else fails, **back up your library** and reinstall iTunes.

You should also make sure you have the most current version of iTunes.

Refer this tutorial for information on [how to transfer and sync contents from iPad to Mac](http://www.iphone-mac.com/how-to-transfer-and-sync-contents-from-ipad-to-mac.html).